# Tailwind custom color in preset

Tags: tailwind-css

If I'm using the default color palette, I can use the color in a preset like:

```
const colors = require("tailwindcss/colors");

module.exports = {
  theme: {
    colors: {
      support: colors.gray[100]
    },
  },
};
```

But if I'm creating a new color on the config file, how do I access the newly created color in the preset? (in other words, how can I import the colours from the config file)

I was expecting to be able to do:

```
const colors = require("tailwindcss/colors");

module.exports = {
  theme: {
    colors: {
      support: colors.newcolor[100]
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 2):

To customize your palette, you can configure your `colors` under the colors key in the theme section of your `tailwind.config.js` file:

**tailwind.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    colors: {
      'midnight': '#121063',
      'tahiti': '#3ab7bf',
    },
  },
}
```

And this color is available to all the utilities like `text-color` utilities, `border-color` utilities, `background-color` utilities, and more.

And you can use this as

```
<div class="bg-midnight text-tahiti">
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

#### More info

If you want to create a nested palette, you can add like this

**tailwind.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    colors: {
      ...
      'tahiti': {
        100: '#cffafe',
        200: '#a5f3fc',
        300: '#67e8f9',
        400: '#22d3ee',
        500: '#06b6d4',
        600: '#0891b2',
        700: '#0e7490',
        800: '#155e75',
        900: '#164e63',
      },
    },
  },
}
```

And use it like this `bg-tahiti-300`.

Find more resource [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors#using-the-default-colors)